# How to add tableview with cell in xib UIView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, xib

I need to do UIView like this for filter and I need to add UITableView on xib file with cell, but I don't have any idea how to do it, I can not register uitableviewcell in extension of class UIVIEW.

here is an image what I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ZwW.jpg

Comment: You don't need to use a "xib file" ... but first, can you create that table view and the cells as a "normal" table view? If not, you need to start there.

Comment: @DonMag yes sure I can do it like tableView but I need size like in image